# how override sails.js view hook for res.view.js file?

Tags: javascript, view, hook, sails.js

How can I override sails.js view hook for res.view.js file?

How is it possible to customize this file in our project and overwrite it?
In which folder, and with what name?

I cannot find any standard documentation for folder path converting names and details.

Comment: what about it do you want to customize?

Answer (score 2):

In api/responses/*.js

You can create your own responses. In here you can customize what ever you like and even edit the ones that are already there.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses

Example, create api/responses/myView.js

Then you can use `res.myView()`